# Yii facebook login button and check session

Tags: facebook, yii, yii-extensions

I'm trying to make a login with Yii extension yii-facebook-opengraph.
I install the login widget without a problem.

I have two problems:

- First: After login popup close. I dont know how to redirect to loged
  in page (the popup close and stay in the same page). I want to save in a session the userId.

**RESOLVE**:
Edit: SFacebook.php method initJs.

```
        if ($this->async) {
            $init = "window.fbAsyncInit = function(){{$init};

            // whenever the user logs in, we tell our login service
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
                window.location = ' " . Yii::app()->baseUrl."xxxREDIRECT-URLxxx". "';
            });
            };

            (function(d){
             var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
             js.src = '{$script}';
             d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));";
        }
```

- Two: Inside the page i have calls to facebook api. If the user close 
  facebook session, when I try to call facebook api, I have an error,
  so I think in check on every page if the user is logged in or not, in
  this way:

  ```
      try{

          $userId = Yii::app()->session['userId']; 

          if (($userId=="") || ($userId==0)){

              try{

                  $user = Yii::app()->facebook->api('/me');
                  Yii::app()->session['userId'] = $user['id'];
                  Yii::app()->session['userName'] = $user['name'];

                  return true;

              }catch (Exception $e) {
                  $this->redirect(array('Admin/Index')); //LOGIN PAGE
              }


          }else{

              return true;   

          }

      }catch (Exception $e) {

          $this->redirect(array('Admin/Index')); //LOGIN PAGE

      }
  ```

Comment: have you completely resolved your issue? if you have, you can add your own answer, and accept it.

Comment: No, just the first part.